# What is mongo $mergeCursors?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

We see a lot of slow queries in mongo logs like below (with pipeline op mergeCursors). We have a shaded mongo with 2 shards with only primaries. What is mergeCursors command? Please let me know if any other information is required.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5571b739f65f7e64bb806362"),
    "op" : "command",
    "ns" : "mongrel.$cmd",
    "command" : {
        "aggregate" : "collection1",
        "pipeline" : [ 
            {
                "$mergeCursors" : [ 
                    {
                        "host" : "endpoint:27005",
                        "id" : NumberLong(82775337156)
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "lockStats" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(12),
            "w" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(2),
            "w" : NumberLong(2680)
        }
    },
    "responseLength" : 12312,
    "millis" : 6142,
    "execStats" : {},
    "ts" : ISODate("2015-06-05T12:35:40.801Z"),
    "client" : "10.167.212.83",
    "allUsers" : [],
    "user" : ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was recently reading this post (http://dbattish.tumblr.com/post/108652372056/joins-in-mongodb) which seems to say that it is an internal aggregate command to merge queries across shards.

Comment: Would the drive by downvoter please explain why, so I can fix the answer?